# How to get cell evaluation output to a pdf file?

Tags: output

How can I divert the output of a cell evaluation, which appears below a cell, instead to an external file, say a pdf file?

Comment: Do you mean `Export`?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
{{1, a}, {a, 2}}
Export["C:/tcdata/myfile.pdf", %]
```